# Extracting array from JSON type body in Spring

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, postman, crud

I want to extract an array from the request body in postman. This is my Request Body:

```
{
        "productid": 1,
        "ordernum": 9,
        "actionid": 1,
        "typeid": 2,
        "Data":["abc","xyz"]
}
```

I'm using Spring boot and want to extract the ["abc,"xyz"] array and assign it to a String[] array. How can this be done.

This is a snippet of my mapping function.

```
@PostMapping("/testingpost")
    public Data addRow(@RequestBody DataRequest request) { 
         String[] responseArr = ??
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `DataRequest` is modeled after the JSON message as specified in your question:

```
public class DataRequest {
    @JsonProperty("productid")
    private Integer productId;

    [...]

    @JsonProperty("Data")
    private String[] data;

    // getters and setters
    
    [...]
}
```

You should be able to simply return the `Data` array using the corresponding attribute as follows:

```
@PostMapping
public String[] something(@RequestBody DataRequest request) {
    return request.getData();
}
```